# How can I get access to another model class attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-models

I have two model class called order.rb and customer.rb:

order.rb

```
 class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :customer

validates :customer_id, :name, :age, :presence => true

 def self.to_csv
        attributes = %w{ to_param name age }
        CSV.generate(headers: true) do |csv|
          csv << attributes

              all.each do |t|
                csv << attributes.map{ |attr| t.send(attr) }
          end
        end
      end
```

customer.rb

```
class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :order, primary_key: "customer_id"
has_many :orders

validates :phone_number, :name,:email,:presence => true, allow_blank: true
```

My question is how do I get the `customer.rb` data such as it attributes email and name. Then add it to the `order.rb` data. If you look at the `order.rb` model I can get its attributes that is listed: name and age, but I am trying to get the `customer.rb` attributes such as the email, name and phone_number. 
However, I can get access to one email only if I apply the method display below and it print out the same email over and over again. Thanks in advance if someone can help me.

```
def to_param
  Customer.new.email
  Customer.all.first.email
end
```

Comment: Why do you have `belongs_to` associations in both the model. As it looks it should be Customer `has_many` orders . Isn't it ?

Comment: @dkp I forgot to add it to my model but I went back and change it.

Comment: You have added it to `Order` modal, rather you should add it to `Customer` model like this `has_many :orders`

Comment: @dkp you are correct I place it in the wrong model class, sorry. How can I get access to another model class attributes

Comment: You can deligate `Customer` attributes in `Order` model like this `deligate :name,:email, to: :customer, prefix: "customer"` . Now you can do like this  `Order.first.customer_email`

Comment: OR, you can simply get `Customer` attributes in `Order` using association. Like you can do `Order.first.customer.name` or `Order.first.customer.email`

Comment: @dkp where do I put Order.first.customer_email in my program.

Comment: Yes, you can put it any where in your code. But you can test it now in your `rails console` as well.

Comment: @dkp I have something similar to that above: def to_param
  Customer.new.email
  Customer.all.first.email
end  From this code how can I add Order.first.customer.email

Comment: You can remove this line from your `Order` model `belongs_to :order, primary_key: "customer_id"` and hopefully you have foreign key `customer_id` column in `orders` table.

Comment: @dkp Yes I do, thanks for that info. however can you show me how to add Order.first.customer.email to this method def to_param "code goes here" end

Comment: `Customer.all.first.email` this will return the first email id  saved in your `customers` table. What do you want to do exactly ?

Comment: @dkp I understand how to return the first email but I would like to return all the email

Comment: `Customer.pluck(:email)` this would return you all the email ids stored in `customers` table.

Comment: @dkp  When I do Customer.pluck(:email) it return all the emails on each slot of the table. I am trying return each email on a different slot of the table.

Comment: Please check below answer.

Comment: @dkp when I run that code it return all the attributes such as name, emails, and phone number. Also it do not return the email ids one after another. It return all the emails in each slot of the table. – user2803053 5 mins ago

Comment: I could not understand the question, can u explain it more simpler ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will return email ids one after a other -

```
  Customer.all.each do |customer|
      customer.email 
  end
```

Comment: when I run that above code it return all the attributes such as name, emails, and phone number. Also it do not return the email ids one after another. It return all the emails in each slot of the table.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :customer

  def self.to_csv
    attributes = %w{ phone_number name age }
    CSV.generate(headers: true) do |csv|
      csv << attributes
      all.each do |t|
        # Note: Considering the attributes are defined in `Customer` model. 
        #   It will get the `customer` of every order and send the message like 
        #     `email`, `name` and maps the responses to the messages
        csv << attributes.map { |attr| t.customer.send(attr) }
      end
    end
  end
end

class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :orders

  validates :phone_number, :name, :email, :presence => true, allow_blank: true
  ...
end
```

If all the attributes might not be available in `Order` model then you can delegate the ones which will be missing to `Customer` model.

```
# in order.rb    
deligate :name, :email, :phone_number, to: :customer, allow_nil: true

# Then this will work; no need of `.customer` as message will be delegated
csv << attributes.map { |attr| t.send(attr) }
```

`:allow_nil` - if set to true, prevents a `NoMethodError` to be raised. [See this for more info about delegation](http://apidock.com/rails/Module/delegate).

Comment here if need further assistance.

Comment: i follow the steps but I run across the same problem. It return all the attributes and it do not return each email

Comment: which one did you try? the former or later? It should have worked. please see carefully and make sure are not missing anything. I am here to help

Comment: I got it to work thanks for the help. the link on delegation help guide me to the correct answer

Comment: ok then click the checkmark if this answer is helpful; it will help future visitors.